# Why is it O-Cl-O and not O-O-Cl?

Tags: molecules, lewis-structure, valence-bond-theory

I'm currently preparing my exam and while I did never think about this question during the course, it begins to confuse me right now...

Why is it the structure of $\ce {ClO_{2}-}$ like $\ce {O-Cl-O}$ and not like $\ce {O-O-Cl}$?

I know how to place the covalent bonds and the electrons, but I don't know how to figure out the basic structure of the molecule. Is there a relatively simple rule to solve (and understand) such relatively simple molecules?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a relatively simple rule to solve (and understand) such
>   relatively simple molecules?

The most electropositive atom is usually at the center of a molecule because

- a "central atom" implies that there are multiple (more than 1) bonds to the central atom. If the central atom is relatively electropositive, then it will be better able to share its electrons and form bonds with other atoms, at least more so than an electronegative central atom would.
- electronegative atoms tend to carry multiple lone pairs of electrons. If this electronegative atom and all of its lone pairs were at the center of the molecular structure, then we would have many more destabilizing (lone-pair - bonding pair) electron-electron repulsions, then if all of these lone pairs were on the periphery of the molecule.

Answer (score 0):

Try to draw the structure of $\ce{ClO2-}$. It will like this :

[image]

If you see the structure it is $\ce{O−Cl−O}$  and not $\ce{O−O−Cl}$.

Chlorine is in the center because Least electronegative atom will be at center. You can refer this links: [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTKW7nDzVCA) and  [chemistry education](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/sstutorial/Text7/Tx72/tx72.html)

Comment: The right O and Cl are connected by a covalent double bond? But Cl would then have 5 electron pairs which is wrong. (Furthermore, my textbook says, that the atoms are connected by single bonds only.)

Comment: @Michael this is $\ce{ClO2-}$ Lewis Structure, if you want to know how to draw structure you should see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTKW7nDzVCA).

Comment: Doesn't $O-O-Cl$ have lower formal charges than $O-Cl=O$? Why is having Chlorine as the central atom preferable to having oxygen as it?

Comment: @user2612743 Least electronegative atom will be at center.

Comment: @Freddy Why is it the least electronegative? Is it most conducive to "sharing" electrons/forming bonds?

Comment: @user2612743 See the rules for drawing Lewis structures of mlecules [here](http://www.chem.wisc.edu/deptfiles/genchem/sstutorial/Text7/Tx72/tx72.html)

Comment: @Freddy Unless I missed something that doesn't explain *why* the least electronegative is in the center

Comment: @user2612743 Frankly i don't know why but thats the rule! Yes and i also know Hydrogen is exception.

Comment: @Freddy: The Lewis structure in your answer says that there's a double bond between the right O and the Cl, right? That's not what my book tells and that's also not what I get. I get only single bonds.

Comment: @Michael I have given [youtube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTKW7nDzVCA) in second comment to Michael you can refer that if you have any doubt about how the structure came.